# How to fix azure blobs authentication error Authorization Header/Mac signature doesnt match

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blobs and uploading images as blobs into a container, everything was working yesterday but for some reason today when I am trying to create a blob (uploading an image) I am getting an error:

```
(node:5412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:742c79aa-601e-0046-2f47-bd0f64000000
Time:2019-02-05T11:38:04.9687033Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'iEGyntz0xOL6HddnoD/F6GxkHjyZlxEGTQ21OjlWCy4=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT


67

application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

I created the container already and it has container and blob access set which is how it was working before. I Get back a containerURL and a blobURL as if the blob was created 
I get back the Container URL:

`https://facerstorage.blob.core.windows.net/suspects`

and I also get the BlobURL:

```
"https://facerstorage.blob.core.windows.net/suspects/whoever.jpg"
```

but when I check in the azure dashboard inside the container the blob isn't there.

I also checked my time, I was at UTC+2 and switched it to UTC 0 which is equal to the GMT I am getting from the server, but it was working yesterday at GMT+2 as well. 
Not sure why I am getting this, everything was working before.

Thanks

### UPDATE 1:

I put the code doing the uploading into a try catch block and I got the error in this format :

```
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:6b27b7c2-601e-0024-474c-bdcd43000000\nTime:2019-02-05T12:14:44.3155159Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request \'n/0RjbOhVCOHSkWlq4JWqPsgMe7UxkuyrA1HV1Y1AcY=\' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: \'PUT\n\n\n67\n\napplication/xml; charset=utf-8\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-client-request-id:ce83a49c-51fb-476e-b4ab-25968c162d82\nx-ms-date:Tue, 05 Feb 2019 12:14:43 GMT\nx-ms-version:2018-03-28\n/facerstorage/watchlist/CHRISTOPHER%20ROBERT%20METSOS.jpg\ncomp:blocklist\ntimeout:60000\'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>',
     headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
     status: 403 },
  body:
   { message:
      'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:6b27b7c2-601e-0024-474c-bdcd43000000\nTime:2019-02-05T12:14:44.3155159Z' } }
```

Here is my code that is doing the uploading I took the base from the azure sdk and modified it a little bit:

```
async function uploadImage(aborter, containerURL, filePath, blobName) {
    try{ 
    filePath = path.resolve(filePath);

    const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, blobName);
    console.log("Blob created, URL is: " + JSON.stringify(blockBlobURL.url));

    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {
      highWaterMark: FOUR_MEGABYTES,
    });

    const uploadOptions = {
        bufferSize: FOUR_MEGABYTES,
        maxBuffers: 5,
    };


    //SAVE URL TO DB
    addToDB(blobName, blockBlobURL.url);



    return await uploadStreamToBlockBlob(
                    aborter, 
                    stream, 
                    blockBlobURL, 
                    uploadOptions.bufferSize, 
                    uploadOptions.maxBuffers);
  } catch (err) {console.log(err)}
}
```

### UPDATE #2

-Checked Azure Keys and refreshed them and replaced.

-Able to make containers without getting any authentication errors.

-Tried using regular uploadLocalFile instead of stream get the error as well.

Comment: Are you using Node SDK or writing your own code to consume REST API? It would be helpful if you can share your code.

Comment: added the code, I am using the azure blob sdk I just modified the function a bit.

Comment: @Jack There seems to be not any issue in your code. Please check the access key of your Azure Storage account on Azure portal to make sure whether be changed.

Comment: Hi Peter, My authentication key was fine, I even refreshed it now and put in the new one.  I also tried and can make a new container in my app and it shows up in the azure dashboard.  Not sure why I get this when uploading the stream

Comment: I saw this https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/348 that says they fixed this issue in 2014 though it seems to be from a linux machine but I guess not really fixed.

Comment: Also tried using uploadLocalFile instead of stream also doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, the files I was uploading had spaces between the name e.g. "Jhon Marcus"

Although I had already dealt with this using:

```
fileName = fileName.replace(/\s/gi, '-')
```

replacing the spaces before, I had afterwards added a category to the bloname to create a virtual directory and the category had spaces so it was /my cat/filename and it was the space in the category name that broke it.

But at the end replacing the spaces with - fixed my issue.

Thanks for all who helped

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error , my storage account key was wrong , changing that to correct one fixed my issue